# How to get greater value of row in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm working on a project and i need help. I need to check student's grade if he take the subject 2 times, then take **the bigger value** of the grade. Let's say he get E on his first attempt on that subject, then he take it again and get B. Or in other case, in his 1st attempt he got C, then when he re-take that subject, he got D.

here is my table

```
id_krs | id_mhs | id_sub | status | grade 
------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------
1      | 3      | 1      | B      | A
2      | 3      | 3      | B      | A
3      | 3      | 4      | B      | E
4      | 3      | 4      | U      | B
5      | 3      | 7      | B      | C
6      | 3      | 7      | U      | E
```

B = 1st, U = retry.

**Edit**

I'm sorry for the question that not clear.
My query is

```
 $user=Auth::user()->username;
    $mhs = DB::table('krs as f')
        ->select('f.id_sub','f.status','f.grade','f.id_krs',DB::raw("(
                        CASE 
                            when f.grade= 'E' then 0 
                            when f.grade= 'D' then 1 
                            when f.grade= 'D+' then 1.5 
                            when f.grade= 'C' then 2 
                            when f.grade= 'B' then 3
                            when f.grade= 'B+' then 3.5
                            when f.grade= 'A' then 4 end 
                        )   
                        AS angka_kredit"))
                        ->join('mhs_pt as a','a.id_mhs_pt','=','f.id_mhs_pt')
                        ->orderBy('angka_kredit','asc')
                        ->groupBy('f.id_sub')                           
                        ->where('a.no_mhs',$user)
                        ->get();
```

when i make the result into json, the result is

```
[{"id_sub":30,"status":"B","grade":"D","id_krs":45,"angka_kredit":"1.0"},
{"id_sub":31,"status":"B","grade":"C","id_krs":46,"angka_kredit":"2.0"},
{"id_sub":29,"status":"B","grade":"A","id_krs":38,"angka_kredit":"4.0"}]
```

while my data in my table is

```
+--------+-----------+----------+--------+-------+
| id_krs | id_mhs_pt | id_sub   | status | grade | 
+--------+-----------+----------+--------+-------+
|     38 | 3         | 29       | B      | A     | 
|     45 | 3         | 30       | B      | D     |  
|     46 | 3         | 31       | B      | C     | 
|  18393 | 3         | 31       | U      | A     | 
+--------+-----------+----------+--------+-------+
```

What i meant is the result query should show the id_krs 18393 instead of 46, because it have higher grade. Many thank's!

Comment: Hint: look at `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` in MySQL. Have a go at writing the query, post your code and we can help you from there.

Comment: Nothing is clear what you asking about please read 1st how to ask a good question.Thanks

Comment: Please clarify the name of each column, as well as the difference between `status` and `grade`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your model name is : StudentGrade, the current subject id is 4, and the current student id is 3, you can try this query:

```
$grade = StudentGrade::where('id_sub', '=', 4)->where('id_mhs', '=', 3)->orderBy('grade', 'asc')->first();
```

Hope this can help you to the right direction :)